# How can I populate a select list with time?

Tags: php, unix-timestamp, selectlist

I want to populate a select list such that it increments for each 5 minutes starting from 00:00 up til 23:55. I need to do this in UNIX time as well.

Below is what I've done but I've just realised that doing `strtotime("18:00")` doesn't actually give me that hour specifically. I also have a select list of dates, for example a date can be "Tues 6 march 2012" (with the unix format being: `1330992000`). I want to be able to take the two selected values and then add the two unix timestamps together so I can insert it into the database. For example, a user selects the time 17:00 which will give me `1332950400`  (I know this is wrong) and then the date Tues 6 march 2012 which will give me `1330992000`. I want to then be able to add the two timestamps together so I get 18:00 Tues 6 March 2012 in Unix timestamp format.

```
public function timeSelectList()
{
    //using actual unix time instead of strtotime to save it from having to call the function each time. 
    $startTime = 1332889200; //strtotime('00:00');
    $endTime =  1332975300; //strtotime('23:55');
    $now = $startTime;

    $startSelectList = '<label for="startSelect">Start Time</label><select name="startSelect" id="startSelect">';
    $endSelectList = '<label for="endSelect">End Time</label><select name="endSelect" id="endSelect">';
    //populates the select list with the starting date of the course up to the next six months
    while($now <= $endTime)
    {
        if($now == 1332950400)// strtotime('17:00')
        {
            $startSelectList .= '<option value="'.$now.'" selected="selected">'.date('H:i', $now).'</option>';
            $endSelectList .= '<option value="'.$now.'">'.date('H:i', $now).'</option>';
        }
        else if($now == 1332954000)//strtotime('18:00')
        {
            $startSelectList .= '<option value="'.$now.'">'.date('H:i', $now).'</option>';
            $endSelectList .= '<option value="'.$now.'" selected="selected">'.date('H:i', $now).'</option>';
        }
        else
        {
            $startSelectList .= '<option value="'.$now.'">'.date('H:i', $now).'</option>';
            $endSelectList .= '<option value="'.$now.'">'.date('H:i', $now).'</option>';
        }
        $now += 300; //increment 5 minutes (300 seconds = 5 minutes
    }

    $startSelectList .= '</select>';
    $endSelectList .= '</select>';

    return $startSelectList.$endSelectList;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a little unclear what the resulting form looks like. Nonetheless, in these situations it is easier to do *string math* than *date math*.

For example, add the date and time together as a string, then determine it's timestamp.

```
$date_string = $date . ' ' . $time; // '2012-03-28 18:00'
$timestamp = strtotime($date_string);
```

**Note:** You'll of course want to do some validation or string formatting beforehand. But the above should be the final piece you need.